# Criar forma no HTML e sobrepor no navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3, nav-bar

Preciso de idéias de como fazer um navbar assim. Tentei com clip-path, mas não sei se é uma boa. Essas curvas do triangulo e principalmente a da barra verde me complicam a vida. O navbar é em bootstrap 3.

```css
.navbar-brand {
  background-color: blue;
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 98% 16%, 60% 94%, 43% 94%, 3% 15%, 0 0);
 clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 98% 16%, 60% 94%, 43% 94%, 3% 15%, 0 0);
  width: 280px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
 left:50%;
  margin-left:-140px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-brand"></div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como vc falou que estava usando Bootstrap 3 fiz esse modelo com base no `Navbar` original do *framework*.

Resumidamente são alguns *pseudo-elementos* com `positions` e transforme. Recomendo que vc estudo os detalhes no código CSS para entender o que foi feito.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O elemento branco é um quadrado construído em um *pseudo-elemento* na própria `nabvar`, ele foi rotacionado `45deg`, com um `border-radius` e alinhado no centro da `navbar`

A barra verde tem um `box` dentro, esse `box` foi alinhado no meio da barra com `margim` e depois usei propriedade para transformar o elemento `transform: perspective(2.5px) rotateX(-1deg);` Repare que ajustando a perspectiva vc ajusta o angula das laterais do `box`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já para fazer a curvatura que na junção do `box` com a barra eu usei um pseudo-elemento `::after, esse`::after`na verdade é um quadrado com um radial-gradiente que vai do transparente para a mesma cor de fundo da barra, o verde, nessa imagem eu coloquei vermelho para vc entender melhor como é o elemento. Depois eu coloquei um`transform: skewX(35deg);`para ajustar esse elemento com o mesmo angulo da lateral do`box` e ficar tudo direitinho.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Segue o código da imagem acima.**

**OBS1:** Pode ser que vc precise fazer um tratamento responsivo para telas de celulares, minha recomendação é dar um `display:none` em todos esse elementos "alegóricos"

**OBS2:** Deixe a curvatura do lado esquerdo para vc fazer e ver por conta própria como tudo foi montado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<style>
.navbar-default {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #003780;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2
}
.navbar-default::after {
    content: "";
    width: 260px;
    height: 260px;
    border-radius: 60px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 16px black;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-88%, -17%);
    transform-origin: center;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
}

.borda {
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #97cd32;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.borda::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    /* background-color: red; */
    /* border-radius: 50%; */
    left: calc(50% - 166px);
    top: 30px;
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle at bottom left, transparent 0%, transparent 68%, #97cd32 69%);
    transform: skewX(35deg);
}

.box {
    position:relative;
    width: 280px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #97cd32;
    margin: auto;
    transform: perspective(2.5px) rotateX(-1deg);
    border-radius: 10px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
    
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<div class="borda">
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: E olha que eu só pedi dicas. Eu tinha acabado de descobrir que o triangulo na verdade é um quadrado com bordas arredondadas e com um giro de 45 graus. Agora da barra verde, vou estudar teu código para aprender a fazer. Muitíssimo obrigado.

Comment: @CarlosFagianiJr eu um quadrado mesmo rss, na barra verde tem um retângulo, só que rotacionado com perspectiva rss. Se tiver duvida de algum detalhe eh do falar

Comment: pode ter certeza que estou lendo e aprendendo com teu código, até mesmo pq, vou ter q fazer ele no rodapé, só que invertido.